# How could django model get one field？

Tags: django

I know how to get a line,but I don't know how to get one field.
for exmple,there is a table,have id,title,content fields.

```
ModelsExample.objects.filter(id = showid)# get one line.
```

how to get title field only?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`values`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for that matter. Depending on how you would like to use tour context:

- Use of `values()` example:

  ```
  r = ModelsExample.objects.filter(id=showid).values('title')
  ```

  This would return something like: `[{'title': 'My title'}]` so you could access it with `r[0]['title']`.
- Use of `values_list()` example:

  ```
  r = ModelsExample.objects.filter(id=showid).values_list('title')
  ```

  This would return something like: `[('My title',)]` so you could access it as `r[0][0]`.
- Use of `values_list(flat=True)` example:

  ```
  r = ModelsExample.objects.filter(id=showid).values_list('title', flat=True)
  ```

  This would return something like: `['My title']` so you could access it as `r[0]`.

And of course you can always access each field of the model as:

```
r = ModelsExample.objects.get(id=showid)
r.title
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get only one field like this

```
ModelsExample.objects.filter(id = showid).values('title')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways:

```
ModelsExample.objects.filter(id=showid)[0].title
ModelsExample.objects.filter(id=showid).only('title')[0].title
```

or

```
ModelsExample.objects.get(id=showid).title
```

First fetch collection and get first element. If collection don't have elements they raise `IndexError`.

Second get one element. If in DB You have more elements they raise `MultipleObjectsReturned`. If cannot found any row, they raise `NoResultFound`.